# Reopening of a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Hi. Recently a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45628/what-gwibber-alternatives-are-there/45648#45648) of mine was closed due to being an exact duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4922/what-microblogging-clients-are-available). While I always skim-through the questions with similar titles, I hadn't thought to search under "microblogging" too. After looking through that community wiki for an application similar to what my criteria for the question was, I found that not a single one of the applications listed were quite what I had asked about originally.

Can I edit the question to achieve a more narrow criteria? I'm not sure of what I should do.

Comment: +1 - I had a similar problem on SU when I failed to use the search terms 'bullet-proof' and 'mother' before asking my own similar question. No kidding.

Comment: Seriously? That's just plain weird lol!

Comment: Actually, the CW is [here](http://superuser.com/questions/14424/how-can-i-make-my-moms-windows-pc-bullet-proof). To be fair, the tags are `windows` `security` `virus` `malware`. I guess the point is that it's often hard to track these dupes down before the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you narrow or change the scope of your question simply flag it for moderator attention (once edited) requesting it be reopened.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I will do just that.